# Blender Object with a Box Collider doesn't revert other object's movement direction but a simple cube does

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, blender

I'm trying to reproduce a breakout-like game in 3D to learn Unity. I designed my bricks in blender and imported them as a .blend files into Unity. I applied a Box Collider to the brick objects. I want them to revert the movement direction of the ball on collision. It works perfectly fine with the paddle and walls, however the ball passes through the bricks, I made the ball extra slow to make sure it isn't because of the ball moving too fast. The collision gets detected, even Destroy() on collision works, but changing the velocity of the ball doesn't. I tested the same with a simple cube and it worked perfectly as well. Is there something I need to consider when using objects made in blender? Here is my code for the ball:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maxX;
    public float maxZ;
    private Vector3 velocity;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        float maxDist = 0.5f * other.transform.localScale.x + 0.5f * transform.localScale.z;
        float actualDist = transform.position.z - other.transform.position.z;
        float distNorm = actualDist / maxDist;
        if (other.CompareTag("Paddle"))
        {
            velocity.z = distNorm * maxZ;
            velocity.x *= -1;
        }
        else if (other.CompareTag("Side Wall"))
        {
            velocity.z *= -1;
        }
        else if (other.CompareTag("Wall"))
        {
            velocity.x *= -1;
        }
        else if (other.CompareTag("Brick"))
        {
            velocity.x *= -1;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        velocity = new Vector3(-maxX, 0, 0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
     
    }
}
```

The bricks have a box collider(isTrigger is off) and I tried adding a rigidbody component too but with no results. The ball is a simple sphere with sphere collider, has "Is Trigger" on and rigidbody with continous collision detection.

I don't know if this is relevant to the problem but I generate the bricks through a script, here is its code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BrickFactory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject emptyBrick, 
                      yellowBrick,
                      orangeBrick, 
                      greenBrick, 
                      cyanBrick, 
                      pinkBrick, 
                      purpleBrick, 
                      darkBlueBrick, 
                      redBrick;
    private GameObject[] brickTypes;

    private int[,] level1 = new int[25,10] {
        {8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8},
        {8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8},
        {7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7},
        {7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7},
        {6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6},
        {6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6},
        {5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5},
        {5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5},
        {4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4},
        {4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4},
        {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
        {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
        {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
        {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6},
        {5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5},
        {5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5},
        {4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4},
        {4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4},
        {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
        {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
        {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
        {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}

     };

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        brickTypes = new GameObject[]{
            emptyBrick,         //empty 0
            yellowBrick,        //yellow 1
            orangeBrick,        //orange 2
            greenBrick,         //green 3
            cyanBrick,          //cyan 4
            pinkBrick,          //pink 5
            purpleBrick,        //purple 6
            darkBlueBrick,      //darkBlue 7
            redBrick            //red 8
        };
        float rowOffset = -7.877f;
        float columnOffset = -7.5f;
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                if(level1[i, j] != 0)
                {
                    GameObject newBrick = Instantiate(brickTypes[level1[i,j]], new Vector3(columnOffset, 1.28f, rowOffset), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                    newBrick.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);
                }
                rowOffset += 1.75f;
            }
            rowOffset = -7.877f;
            columnOffset += 0.6f;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Also a side note: The ball starts magically bouncing off the bricks after it gets back to the paddle and heads back at the bricks.

Edit: I found out this bug only happens when the ball is moving in a perfectly straight line, if I set an initial value for velocity.z instead of only x the movement direction gets changed properly on first collision. However that's not a valid solution. Can it be a bug in Unity's implementation of collisions?

Edit2: The problem was that if the ball hits 2 bricks at once, it executes the code twice which means one turns x into -x and other back into x, is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: `> The ball is a simple sphere with sphere collider, has "Is Trigger" on` - Well, that's exactly what is not letting your sphere to physically interact with boxes - trigger colliders are not behaving like physical body. I'm not sure how your sphere did collided with other boxes, perhaps you've changed `isTrigger` after?

Comment: @Xander from what I understood one of the objects has to have isTrigger on to call the OnTriggerEnter() function. I found out what the problem was and it's when the ball collides with 2 bricks at once, OnTriggerEnter() is called twice and it makes velocity.x turn negative then positive again canceling the desired effect out.

Comment: Ah, I see now, instead of using physics with constraints you are manually calculating new direction of movement, and besides that the logic is completely messed up, no wonder you gen blunder. You should either move on to using physics (set Z axis and rotation constraints, bouncy material etc.) and get rid of clunky manual velocity calculations, or you should do proper vector calculation based on contact points, normals and the rest of things (happily, Unity provides good API under Vector3 class).